# Check if Active Inactive date lies within the Date Range of another Active Inactive Date

Tags: sql, date

Table 1

| Loc_Id | Label_Id | Active_Date | Inactive_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 2022/05/13 | 9999/12/31 |
| 2 | 1001 | 2018/05/20 | 2022/05/12 |
| 3 | 1001 | 2012/06/14 | 2018/05/12 |

Table 2

| Label_Id | Tab2_Active_Date | Tab2_Inactive_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022/05/13 | 9999/12/31 |
| 1001 | 2018/05/22 | 2022/05/12 |
| 1001 | 2012/06/14 | 2018/05/12 |

I want to know which records in Table2 have Tab2_Active Date > Active Date in Table 1 and Tab2_Inactive Date < Inactive Date in Table 1.
For example in this the scenario the date Tab2_Active Date 2018/05/22 mentioned in Table 2 is greater than 2018/05/20 mentioned in table 1.

So the o/p will be

| Loc_Id | Tab2_Active_Date | Tab2_Inactive_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2018/05/22 | 2022/05/12 |

Since I only have only Ids to join as the keys for 2 tables and I need to compare the dates, I cannot take dates to join the tables which results in inaccurate data.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table #T1
(
Loc_Id int,
Label_Id int,
Active_Date date,
Inactive_Date date
)

Create table #T2
(
Label_Id int,
Active_Date date,
Inactive_Date date
)

Insert into #T1 
Select 1, 1001, '2022-05-13', '9999-12-31'
union
Select 2, 1001, '2022-05-20', '2022-05-12'
union
Select 3, 1001, '2022-06-14', '2018-05-12'
union
Select 4, 1001, '2022-07-14', '2018-08-13'


Insert into #T2 
Select  1001, '2022-05-13', '9999-12-31'
union
Select 1001, '2022-05-22', '2022-05-12'
union
Select 1001, '2022-06-14', '2018-05-12'
union
Select 1001, '2022-06-14', '2018-05-12'
union
Select 1001, '2022-07-14', '2018-08-12'


;with Cte as
(
Select Label_Id, Active_Date, Inactive_Date  from #T2
EXCEPT 
Select Label_Id, Active_Date, Inactive_Date from #T1
)
Select t1.Loc_Id, t2.Active_Date, t2.Inactive_Date 
from #T1 t1 
inner join Cte t2 on t1.Label_Id = t2.Label_Id and (t2.Active_Date > t1.Active_Date and t2.Inactive_Date = t1.Inactive_Date)
union 
Select t1.Loc_Id, t2.Active_Date, t2.Inactive_Date 
from #T1 t1 
inner join Cte t2 on t1.Label_Id = t2.Label_Id and (t2.Inactive_Date < t1.Inactive_Date and t2.Active_Date = t1.Active_Date)


Drop table #T1
Drop table #T2
```

Comment: Hi @nitish! This answer can provide more value to the question asker (and others who read this answer later) by providing an explanation of how the code you wrote solves the problem. Would you mind adding that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with

```sql
with t1 as (
    select * from (values
        (1, 1001, '2022-05-13', '9999-12-31'),
        (2, 1001, '2018-05-20', '2022-05-12'),
        (3, 1001, '2012-06-14', '2018-05-12')
    ) as x(Loc_ID, Label_Id, Active_Date, Inactive_Date)
),
t2 as (
    select * from (values
        (1001, '2022-05-13', '9999-12-31'),
        (1001, '2018-05-22', '2022-05-12'),
        (1001, '2012-06-14', '2018-05-12')
    ) as x(Label_Id, Active_Date, Inactive_Date)
)
select t1.*, '||', t2.*
from t1
join t2
    on t2.Active_Date >= t1.Active_Date
    and t2.Inactive_Date <= t1.Inactive_Date
    and (
        t1.Active_Date <> t2.Active_Date 
        or t1.Inactive_Date <> t2.Inactive_Date
    )
```

Ignoring the CTEs (that's just a way to get the data into a tabular structure), the join criteria in the SELECT statement say that there must be partial overlap in the interval (which are the first two predicates on only one of active_date or inactive_date) but not *complete* overlap (which is the compound predicate saying that at least one of active_date or inactive_date must not match).